# How can i make to move on touch "Kinematic" Rigidbody2D?

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

So there is the code with my Character's Rigidbody2D attachment, but he does not move when is set to Kinematic (working only on Dynamic), but I want Kinematic because he collides with Dynamic Objects and i didn't want him to move just left and right on touch.

UI: I'm very beginner, I just want to make my first game for Android and sorry for my english too. :D

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
    //variables
    public float moveSpeed = 300;
    public GameObject character;

    private Rigidbody2D characterBody;
    private float ScreenWidth;


    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        ScreenWidth = Screen.width;
        characterBody = character.GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {
        int i = 0;
        //loop over every touch found
        while (i < Input.touchCount)
        {
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).position.x > ScreenWidth / 2)
            {
                //move right
                RunCharacter(1.0f);
            }
            if (Input.GetTouch(i).position.x < ScreenWidth / 2)
            {
                //move left
                RunCharacter(-1.0f);
            }
            ++i;
        }
    }
    void FixedUpdate()
    {
#if UNITY_EDITOR
        RunCharacter(Input.GetAxis("Horizontal"));
#endif
    }

    private void RunCharacter(float horizontalInput)
    {
        //move player
        characterBody.AddForce(new Vector2(horizontalInput * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0));

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

From [Unity docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-isKinematic.html),

> If isKinematic is enabled, Forces, collisions or joints will not affect the rigidbody anymore.

So instead of applying a force, just change it's position. Something like this:

```
private void RunCharacter(float horizontalInput)
{
    //move player
    characterBody.transform.position += new Vector2(horizontalInput * moveSpeed * Time.deltaTime, 0);

}
```